# Efficient way to convert string to single quote in array on Linux shell

Tags: quoting, string

Case example:

```bsh
Array=( "Mary" "had a __SingleQuote__little__SingleQuote__" "lamb" )
for i in "${Array[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
```

```
Mary
had a __SingleQuote__little__SingleQuote__
lamb
```

I want to **convert** the `__SingleQuote__` string into a **single quote** `'` character, so the array will be:

```bsh
ConvertedArray=( "Mary" "had a 'little'" "lamb" )
for i in "${ConvertedArray[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
```

```
Mary
had a 'little'
lamb
```

Maybe something like:

`ConvertedArray=( "$(echo ${Array[@]} | sed s/___SingleQuote__/\'/ )" )`

But this command yields the wrong results:

```bsh
Array=( "Mary" "had a __SingleQuote__little__SingleQuote__" "lamb" )
ConvertedArray=( "$(echo ${Array[@]} | sed s/___SingleQuote__/\'/ )" )
for i in "${ConvertedArray[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
```

```
Mary had a __SingleQuote__little__SingleQuote__ lamb
```

What is the **proper command** to do this on a Linux shell (Bash if the solution needs to be specific) ?

I could implement a loop, but the array could be very long, so **efficiency** when using shell tools is preferred.

**Tested**:

- The `tr` command, but it transliterates character by character.
- The 'sed'  command, but I have problems dealing with the single quotes the 'sed' syntax needs.

Answer (score 3):

In `bash`, you should be able to apply a global parameter substitution to an array element by element:

```
$ Array=( "Mary" "had a __SingleQuote__little__SingleQuote__" "lamb" )
$ ConvertedArray=( "${Array[@]//__SingleQuote__/\'}" )
$ printf '%s\n' "${ConvertedArray[@]}"
Mary
had a 'little'
lamb
```

See for example [Search and replace: Arrays](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replacearrays)

Comment: Is this Bash expansion?

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez yes - see for example [Search and replace: Arrays](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace)

Comment: Well, the index are not kept, as long as the original array could have "holes" (i.e: `0 1 3`) on its positions that will not be transferred to the final array (that will fill `0 1 2`). But that was not included in the original question (in fact, we could say this matter is another story), so this answer is correct. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are wanting to do this in `bash` (or you wouldn't be using an array to start with).

```
$ echo "${Array[@]//__SingleQuote__/\'}"
Mary had a 'little' lamb
```

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${Array[@]//__SingleQuote__/\'}"
Mary
had a 'little'
lamb
```

```
$ ConvertedArray=( "${Array[@]//__SingleQuote__/\'}" )
$ printf '%s\n' "${ConvertedArray[@]}"
Mary
had a 'little'
lamb
```

The above uses the pattern substitution `${parameter//pattern/text}` to replace all occurrences of `__SingleQuote__` with a single quote.  When applied to an array, the operation is performed on each element individually.

---

In a POSIX shell, where we only have a single array, `$@`:

```
set -- "Mary" "had a __SingleQuote__little__SingleQuote__" "lamb"

i=0
while [ "$i" -ne "$#" ]; do
    set -- "$@" "$( printf '%s\n' "$1" | sed "s/__SingleQuote__/'/g" )"
    shift
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done

printf '%s\n' "$@"
```

This modifies the set of positional parameters by feeding each individual parameter through `sed` to convert the placeholder string to a single quote character. It does the modification on the first positional parameter and adds the result to the end of `$@`.  Then it shifts the first parameter off the array and repeats until all the elements have been processed.

The above would produce

```
Mary
had a 'little'
lamb
```

Comment: Excuse me but, why using an array means wanting to do this on Bash?

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez Bash is the most common shell that has arrays. The POSIX shell specification has only one array and that is the array of positional parameters (command line arguments). The syntax `var=(...)` will cause a syntax error in POSIX shells that are not extended to support arrays, such as `dash` or `pdksh`.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, this will print what you ask for:

```
printf '%s\n' "${Array[@]//__SingleQuote__/\'}"
```

But since you ask for a new array with the corrected values, then use:

```
ConvertedArray=( "${Array[@]//__SingleQuote__/\'}" )
```

Of course, the indexes of ConvertedArray will be numeric from 0 and up. That seems like not a problem but since you mention it in comments (on other answer) keep reading.

---

#### Sparse Array

If the array is defined as:

```
$ Array=( [2]="Mary" [5]="had a __SingleQuote__little__SingleQuote__" [8]="lamb" )
```

Then the array is sparse (has some holes):

```
$ declare -p Array
declare -a Array=([2]="Mary" [5]="had a __SingleQuote__little__SingleQuote__" [8]="lamb")
```

To solve that you need a loop:

```
$ for i in "${!Array[@]}"; do
>     ConvertedArray[i]="${Array[i]//__SingleQuote__/\'}"
> done
$ declare -p ConvertedArray
declare -a ConvertedArray=([2]="Mary" [5]="had a 'little'" [8]="lamb")
```

And

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${ConvertedArray[@]}"
Mary
had a 'little'
lamb
```